# AngularJS conditionals in HTML Attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

How would you change an `html` attribute based on the model?

I'm trying to change an input's placeholder text based on a length of an array:

```
<input placeholder="{{todos.length ? 'Insert todo' : 'Insert your first todo'}}" />
```

But that doesn't seem to work...

[JS Bin code example](http://jsbin.com/evohip/1).

Comment: can you explain better what is not working and what response you get?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like:
`<input placeholder="{{todos.length>N ? 'Insert todo' : 'Insert your first todo'}}" />`

Comment: Hey guys, check out this jsbin, what am I doing wrong? If I remove the input placeholder code, the list populates... http://jsbin.com/evohip/1 thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across this (like I just did via Google), it looks like Angular recently added support for the ternary operator in expressions. I just used it successfully in 1.2.16 to dynamically update a tooltip (title) attribute. It seems to have first appeared in the documentation for 1.2.17, although they still generally discourage its use:

From: [AngularJS: Developer Guide: Expressions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/docs/guide/expression#no-control-flow-statements)

> Apart from the ternary operator (a ? b : c), you cannot write a control flow statement in an expression. The reason behind this is core to the Angular philosophy that application logic should be in controllers, not the views. If you need a real conditional, loop, or to throw from a view expression, delegate to a JavaScript method instead.

Comment: I needed this in a template for a directive I was building. Probably should have put everything in a .link() instead of the template, but the template (at the moment) feels so much simpler. Problem: I needed to optionally include a random attribute "data-toggle" and couldn't figure out how. Ternary operator worked like a charm: <a data-toggle="(disabled?'':'drop down')">

Comment: Whoops, meant to write: <a data-toggle="{{(disabled?'':'drop down')}}">

Answer (score 26):

The ternary operator doesn't seem to work in this case, instead of doing this

```
{{cond ? true : false}}
```

Change it to

```
{{ exp && true || false }}
```

So your `placeholder` attribute would look like this (I have shortened it for demonstration purposes)

```
placeholder="{{todos.length > 0 && 'Insert' || 'Insert first'}}"
```

Comment: jm- thanks that works... so Angular Expression doesn't support the ternary shorthand?

Comment: it seems it doesn't and it makes sense since the framework is very oriented towards testability and you don't want logic in your views. So ideally you would just call a function defined in your controller that returns a string.

Comment: oic so something like `getInputPlaceholder()` and have my logic in there?

Comment: I think in this case you can get away with it, since it's a placeholder. Perhaps just have a `isEmpty()` in your controller which you can test easily and use it for more use cases, then leave the message to display in the views.

Comment: Awesome solution. This worked for me in a case where I should dynamically change the value of a directive custom attribute inserted in a field inside a ng-repeat loop. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This one didn't work inside a **directive** I am building. so for example if I write ui-tinymce='{{getIsEditable()? tinyMceOptionsSmall : tinyMceOptionsSmallReadonly}}. inside the $scope.getIsEditable function - the variable $scope or $rootscope is not initialized. hence I cannot test any scope related variables