# AngularJS conditional attribute (directive)

Tags: angularjs, attributes

The concept:

```
<form-field ng-repeat="field in fields" field-model='settings[field.name]'
   {{field.match == undefined && '' || 'field-match="settings[field.match]"'}}>
</form-field>
```

As you can see, i'm trying to get conditional attribute - if field.match is set - I'd like to get:

`<form-field field-model='settings[field.name]' field.match="settings[field.match]"></form-field>`

otherwise:

`<form-field field-model='settings[field.name]'></form-field>`

Unfortunately I got `Error: The string contains invalid characters.`

I tried (? : ) syntax with the same result, but I found [AngularJS conditionals in HTML Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780788/angularjs-conditionals-in-html-attribute) that it should be && || syntax... What I'm doing wrong?

**edited**
Here's my directive:

```
KPNDirectives.directive("formField", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:true,
    scope: {
      fieldModel : '=', 
      fieldMatch : '=' 
    },
    template:"<div></div>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var type = attrs.fieldType || 'text';
      var requiredAttr = attrs.fieldRequired ? ' required' : ""
      var requiredHelp = ""
      var matchAttr = ""
      var matchHelp = ""
      console.log(attrs);
      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty('fieldMatch')) {
        matchAttr = " password-match=\"fieldMatch\"";
        matchHelp = '<span ng-show="form.'+attrs.fieldName+'.$error.unique">NOT UNIQUE</span>';
      } else {
        matchAttr = ""
        matchHelp = ""
      }
      if (attrs.fieldRequired == "true") {
        var requiredAttr="required"
        var requiredHelp = '<span ng-show="form.'+attrs.fieldName+'.$error.required">REQUIRED</span>';
      } else {
        requiredAttr = ""
        requiredHelp = ""
      }

      var htmlText =  
      '<div class="form-group" ng-form="form" ng-class="{true: \'has-error\', false: \'has-success\'}[form.'+attrs.fieldName+'.$invalid]">'+
      '<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="'+attrs.fieldName+'">'+attrs.fieldLabel+'</label>'+
      '<div class="col-sm-6">'+ 
      '<input class="form-control" type="'+type+'" placeholder="enter valid name" name="'+attrs.fieldName+'" ng-model="fieldModel" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 '+ matchAttr + requiredAttr+'/>'+
      '<span class="help-block">'+
      requiredHelp +
      matchHelp+
      '<span ng-show="form.'+attrs.fieldName+'.$error.minlength">TOO LESS CHARS</span>'+
      '<span ng-show="form.'+attrs.fieldName+'.$error.maxlength">TOO MUCH CHARS</span>'+
      '&nbsp;'+
      '</span>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
      // console.log(htmlText)
      element.append(htmlText);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope); 
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates and in general parseable text only goes **inside** attribute values (when some directive uses them) or in plain text nodes, surrounded by curlies.

You can obtain the needed result by putting your codintional inside of the `field-match` attibute, like

```
<form-field ng-repeat="field in fields" field-model='settings[field.name]'
   field-match="{{field.match && settings[field.match]}}">
</form-field>
```

Edit (after the OP added his code):

To interpolate values in attributes, use `attrs.$observe` (see [ng.$compile.directive.Attributes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile.directive.Attributes) ) in the link function, instead of linking the attribute in the isolated scope definition.

```
attrs.$observe("fieldMatch", function(fieldMatch) {
     $scope.fieldMatch = fieldMatch;
  }
)
```

Comment: Syntax Error: Token 'field.match' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{field.match && settings[field.match]}}] starting at [field.match && settings[field.match]}}]

Comment: It depends on the directive you use. `form-field` as far as I remember is not part of AngularJS, so be sure to read the documentation, or to manage correctly the value templating if you have written the directive.

Comment: It's my own directive and you're right - it expects that field-match is an object not string.... that's why i'm trying to put whole attr in {{ }}

Comment: If it expects an object, then try with `field-match="field.match && settings[field.match]"`

Comment: Attributes {$$element: JQLite[1], $attr: Object, ngRepeat: "field in tabItem.fields", fieldModel: "settings[field.name]", …}
$$element: JQLite[1]
$$observers: Object
$attr: Object
fieldMatch: "field.match && settings[field.match]"
fieldModel: "settings[field.name]"
fieldName: "newpasscompare"

Comment: so it sets whole field.match && settings[field.match] instead of settings[field.match] or empty string

Comment: See updated answer, use `attrs.$observe` to automatically evaluate expressions in attributes.